# Download Specific Images

Tags: perl

I'm trying to search and download specific images /front and back cover / of a website if found but whatever I do I always download only one of them. What should I change in my code to download both of them if found?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::Escape;
use HTTP::Status;

getCover(...);

sub getCover {

......


  while ($title_found =~ /'(http:\/\/images.blu-ray.com\/movies\/covers\/\d+_.*?)'/gis) {          
     $url = getSite($1);
     if ($title_found =~ /front/) {
        $filename = 'front.jpg';        
     }
     elsif ($title_found =~ /back/) {
        $filename = 'back.jpg';
     }
   }
   my $dir = 'somepath'.$filename;     
   open F, ">", $dir;          
        binmode F;
        print F $url;
   close F; 
   return 0;
}


sub getSite {
 $url = shift;

 print "URL: $url\n";

 my $r;
 my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent();

 $ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.3) Gecko/20030312");

 my $req = new HTTP::Request GET => $url;

 $req->push_header("Accept-Language", "en");

 $req = $ua->prepare_request($req);

 my $res = $ua->request($req);
 my $rc = $res->code;

 if(is_success($rc)){
     $r = $res->as_string();
     $r = $res->content();
     }

     else {
     print "Failed\n";
     }

 return $r;
}
```

Comment: Find out how many times the body of the `while` loop executes with a print statement just inside. Assuming `getSite` does what one would expect this code looks correct.

Comment: I've added what getSite is doing. I have two subs and the print statement is in the second and I get that two $url are found - front and back, but only one is downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the part that saves to `'somepath'.$filename` inside the `while` loop instead of outside it.

Also, it appears that `$title_found` is supposed to contain multiple URLs.  In that case, you need to save `$1` to a temporary variable, and look for front/back in that instead of in `$title_found`.  Otherwise, you'll wind up saving both covers to `front.jpg`.